# Why are the outputs of jaccard_score and jaccard_similarity_score different?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scoring

When trying to use jaccard_similarity_score I get *"Deprecation Warning: jaccard_similarity_score has been deprecated and replaced with jaccard_score. It will be removed in version 0.23. This implementation has surprising behavior for binary and multiclass classification tasks."*

The classic explanation for Jaccard Similarity Score  matches the output from the deprecated jaccard_similarity_score .

However, the results of jaccard_score and jaccard_similarity_score are different (even when trying different parameters, as shown).

```
from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_similarity_score, jaccard_score  
y_pred = [0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1]  
y_true = [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0] 
print("jaccard_similarity_score=",jaccard_similarity_score(y_true, y_pred),'\n')  
for param in ['weighted', 'micro', 'macro']:  
    print(param, " jaccard_score=", jaccard_score(y_true, y_pred,  average=param))
```

This is the output of the code above:

```
jaccard_similarity_score= 0.7 

weighted  jaccard_score= 0.5575  
micro  jaccard_score= 0.5384615384615384  
macro  jaccard_score= 0.5125
```

Is there an option that can be applied for the results to be equal ? Is the new jaccard_score working as expected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see the implementation from https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a5d4c61/sklearn/metrics/classification.py#L311

jaccard_similarity_score actually calculates accuracy.

So, actually, `jaccard_similarity_score` is not a good function here.

Answer (score 3):

`from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_similarity_score` needs to be replaced by `from sklearn.metrics import jaccard_score` and new parameter `pos_label` is  required, for e.g. - `jaccard_score(y_test, dt_yhat,pos_label = "PAIDOFF")`. Valid labels for `pos_label` are: `array(['COLLECTION', 'PAIDOFF'], dtype='<U10')`

https://github.com/DiamondLightSource/SuRVoS/issues/103

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact we have a mistake commited at old (Beta) version of Sklearn.

The old Jaccard Class does NOT compute in fact, Jaccard score! It was giving another metric, that is ACCURACY!

So, when I tried (Sklearn 1.2.2):

```
new_sim = accuracy_score(
               y_true=boolean_bag[x],
               y_pred=boolean_bag[y],
)
```

Instead of (Sklearn 0.19.1):

```
new_sim = jaccard_similarity_score(
               y_true=boolean_bag[x],
               y_pred=boolean_bag[y],
)
```

Things go in the right way and if you are using an Udacity notebook (with OLD) code in a new environment, as Google Colab, you can pass the test.